# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Could not load settings for 'WebPortal' - ASP.NET Core React

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I create an ASP.NET Core 3 **React** project and I keep getting this error.

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Could not load settings for 'WebPortal'
>
> GET https://localhost:44367/_configuration/WebPortal 401
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load settings for 'WebPortal'
>
> at AuthorizeService.ensureUserManagerInitialized (AuthorizeService.js:184)
>   at async AuthorizeService.getUser (AuthorizeService.js:24)
>   at async AuthorizeService.isAuthenticated (AuthorizeService.js:15)
>   at async Promise.all (index 0)
>   at async LoginMenu.populateState (LoginMenu.js:26)

Here is the error popped (`AuthorizeService.js`):

```
    async ensureUserManagerInitialized() {
        if (this.userManager !== undefined) {
            return;
        }

        let response = await fetch(ApplicationPaths.ApiAuthorizationClientConfigurationUrl);

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Could not load settings for '${ApplicationName}');
        }

        let settings = await response.json();
        settings.automaticSilentRenew = true;
        settings.includeIdTokenInSilentRenew = true;
        settings.userStore = new WebStorageStateStore({
            prefix: ApplicationName
        });

        this.userManager = new UserManager(settings);
        this.userManager.events.addUserSignedOut(async () => {
            await this.userManager.removeUser();
            this.updateState(undefined);
        });
    }
```

My `ApiAuthorizationConstants.js` file:

```
    export const ApplicationName = 'WebPortal';
    export const QueryParameterNames = {
      ReturnUrl: 'returnUrl',
      Message: 'message'
    };
    export const LogoutActions = {
      LogoutCallback: 'logout-callback',
      Logout: 'logout',
      LoggedOut: 'logged-out'
    };
    export const LoginActions = {
      Login: 'login',
      LoginCallback: 'login-callback',
      LoginFailed: 'login-failed',
      Profile: 'profile',
      Register: 'register'
    };
    const prefix = '/authentication';
    export const ApplicationPaths = {
       DefaultLoginRedirectPath: '/',
       ApiAuthorizationClientConfigurationUrl: '/_configuration/${ApplicationName}',
       ApiAuthorizationPrefix: prefix,
       Login: '${prefix}/${LoginActions.Login}',
       LoginFailed: '${prefix}/${LoginActions.LoginFailed}',
       LoginCallback: '${prefix}/${LoginActions.LoginCallback}',
       Register: '${prefix}/${LoginActions.Register}',
       Profile: '${prefix}/${LoginActions.Profile}',
       LogOut: '${prefix}/${LogoutActions.Logout}',
       LoggedOut: '${prefix}/${LogoutActions.LoggedOut}',
       LogOutCallback: '${prefix}/${LogoutActions.LogoutCallback}',
       IdentityRegisterPath: '/Identity/Account/Register',
       IdentityManagePath: '/Identity/Account/Manage'
     };
```

In the console, I see:

[image: Error console]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is best to narrow the problem down to either the client or server first to understand what code is failing. From the response, we can see that the failure is caused by HTTP 401 response is being returned from the backend server. Please investigate why the backend is returning this response and open a new question for the backend if you are unable to resolve this.

Comment: From the looks of it, 401 means unauthorized. Are you passing the proper tokens to let the backend know who you are? Does _configuration/WebPortal require an authenticated user to call?

Comment: As the other comments suggest, it would be worth adding the raw request/response of the network trace for that 401 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to @Woodz and @Jack comments, I investigate the problem and find out the issue. 
The issue is **Home** page required authorization.I'll post my solution in here and it may help for someone.

**Reason for the Issue**

In my *Startup.cs* class, I enabled authorization for all Controllers. See below code,

```
services.AddMvc(options => {

                //**************Add General Policy *********************
                //User need to be a Authorized system user to access pages except allowAnonymous annotation
                var generalPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                           .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                           .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(generalPolicy));
                options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());


            })
```

**Solution**

- Change Authorization in  **OidcConfigurationController.cs** (Add **AllowAnonymous** *annotation*).

  ```
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public class OidcConfigurationController : Controller
  {
      private readonly ILogger<OidcConfigurationController> _logger;

      public OidcConfigurationController(IClientRequestParametersProvider 
        clientRequestParametersProvider, ILogger<OidcConfigurationController> 
       logger)
      {
          ClientRequestParametersProvider = clientRequestParametersProvider;
          _logger = logger;
       }

      public IClientRequestParametersProvider ClientRequestParametersProvider 
        { get; }

      [HttpGet("_configuration/{clientId}")]
      public IActionResult GetClientRequestParameters([FromRoute]string clientId)
      {
          var parameters = 
                   ClientRequestParametersProvider.GetClientParameters(HttpContext, 
                   clientId);
          return Ok(parameters);
      }
  }
  ```