# Is there a way to fix Unhandled Rejection in ASP.NET, React using Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET MVC & React, I have also added scaffolding items and migrated databases.

I am trying to login or register, but after I have been registered or login, this error shows up, this error always shows.

> Unhandled Rejectiaon (Error): Could not load settings for
> 'Application.Web'
> AuthorizeService.ensureUserManagerInitialized

> AuthorizeService.ensureUserManagerInitialized

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {

        //**************Add General Policy *********************
        //User need to be a Authorized system user to access pages except allowAnonymous annotation
        var generalPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                   .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                   .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(generalPolicy));
        options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());


    });
```

Can anyone help me with this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reference to [Change Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60107195/unhandled-rejection-error-could-not-load-settings-for-webportal-asp-net-c)

Add **AllowAnonymous** To **OidcConfigurationController**

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public class OidcConfigurationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<OidcConfigurationController> _logger;
    
        public OidcConfigurationController(IClientRequestParametersProvider 
          clientRequestParametersProvider, ILogger<OidcConfigurationController> 
         logger)
        {
            ClientRequestParametersProvider = clientRequestParametersProvider;
            _logger = logger;
         }
    
        public IClientRequestParametersProvider ClientRequestParametersProvider 
          { get; }
    
        [HttpGet("_configuration/{clientId}")]
        public IActionResult GetClientRequestParameters([FromRoute]string clientId)
        {
            var parameters = 
                     ClientRequestParametersProvider.GetClientParameters(HttpContext, 
                     clientId);
            return Ok(parameters);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello! I used the code given above, and after running the application it shows the error immediately after the page loaded. Same error, `Unhandled Rejectiaon (Error): Could not load settings for 'Application.Web' AuthorizeService.ensureUserManagerInitialized`

Comment: Hello, i wish i could help with that, but i will try if i found solution i will add comment here, congrats

Comment: Hello, looking forward to this, thank you!\